# Unable to delete Columns in R

Tags: r

I want to delete 2 columns named-ItemID_na and Item.Type1_na. I have below code to delete.

```
test_input<-subset(test_input,select = -c(ItemId_na, Item.Type1_na))
```

i am getting below error-

> Error: unexpected string constant in
>   "test_input<-subset(test_input,select = -c(ItemId_na, Item.Type1_na))

Can you please help as I am new to R.

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: Your code looks fine. My guess is that you have a typo somewhere. Hint: Add spaces in your code. It makes it easier to read and spot errors. Other hint, try to generate a reproducible example and share that rather than just the error message. In creating the reproducible example, you might stumble upon the answer on your own.

Answer (score 3):

Try subsetting your data frame to retain only the columns you want:

```
drops <- c('ItemId_na', 'Item.Type1_na')
test_input <- test_input[ , !(names(test_input) %in% drops)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in the OP's code.  One is that the column names that we need to delete is not quoted.  Second, the `select` argument doesn't take `-` argument.  So we can use `setdiff` to get the column names that are not "ItemId_na" or "Item.Type1_na".

```
subset(test_input,select = setdiff(names(test_input),
            c("ItemId_na", "Item.Type1_na")))
```

---

The `select` option from `dplyr` takes the `-` option

```
library(dplyr)
test_input %>%
       select(-ItemId_na, -Item.Type1_na)
```

#### data

```
test_input <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), Category = c("X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), ItemId_na = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
3L, 3L
), Item.Type1_na = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L)), 
.Names = c("ID", 
"Category", "ItemId_na", "Item.Type1_na"),
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```